# sort and group a java collection

Tags: java

I have an object which has a name and a score. I would like to sort a collection of such objects so that they are grouped by name and sorted by maximum score in each group (and within the group by descending score as well).

let me demonstrate what I intend to achieve. assume I have these objects(name, score):

(a, 3)
(a, 9)
(b, 7)
(b, 10)
(c, 8)
(c, 3)

then I would like them to be sorted like this:

(b, 10)
(b, 7)
(a, 9)
(a, 3)
(c, 8)
(c, 3)

is this feasible with a Comparator? I can't figure it out, so any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: As i understand it, you want sort of the equivalent of `GROUP BY name ORDER BY MAX(score), score DESC`, not `ORDER BY name, score`?

Comment: @user639755: Can you be more specific about what your intentions are? Like Christoffer writes.

Comment: @Marcus: He does provide example input with expected output, writing an `assertEquals` is trivial.

Answer (score 23):

No, you can't do it with a single sort with a single `Comparator`.

You have to:

1. **group by name**
2. **sort the groups, by highest score in group**
3. Then you need to **flatten the groups** back to a list.

## With Java 8

Edit: Since i wrote this answer, Java 8 has come out, which simplifies the problem a lot:

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.util.Comparator.*;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
```

---

```
List<Record> result = records.stream()
    .sorted(comparingInt(Record::getScore).reversed())
    .collect(groupingBy(Record::getName, LinkedHashMap::new, toList()))
    .values().stream()
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(toList());
```

First we sort by score reversed, and then we group using a `LinkedHashMap`, which will preserve the insertion order for the keys, so keys with higher score will come first.

Sorting first is OK if the groups are small, so the redundant compares between objects in different groups don't hurt so much.

Also, with this method, duplicates are preserved.

---

Alternatively, if you don't care about preserving duplicates, you can:

```
Comparator<Record> highestScoreFirst = comparingInt(Record::getScore).reversed();

List<Record> result = records.stream()
        .collect(groupingBy(Record::getName,
                toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(highestScoreFirst))))
        .values().stream()
        .sorted(comparing(SortedSet::first, highestScoreFirst))
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(toList());
```

Where the records are grouped into sorted `TreeSet`s, instead of sorting the values as the first operation of the stream, and then the sets are sorted by their first, highest value.

Grouping before sorting is appropriate if the groups are big, to cut down on redundant compares.

---

## Implementing `Comparable`:

And you can make it shorter by having your record implement `Comparable`

```
public class Record implements Comparable<Record> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Record other) {
        // Highest first
        return -Integer.compare(getScore(), other.getScore());

        /* Or equivalently:
           return Integer.compare(other.getScore(), getScore());
        */
    }
    ...
}
```

---

```
List<Record> result = records.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Record::getName, toCollection(TreeSet::new)))
    .values().stream()
    .sorted(comparing(SortedSet::first))
    .flatMap(Collection::stream)
    .collect(toList());
```

---

## Before Java 8

Edit: Here is a really rough unit test that demonstrates one way to do it. I haven't cleaned it up as much as i would have liked.

Stuff like this is painful in Java, and i would normally use [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) for this.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.*;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class GroupSortTest {

    @Test
    public void testGroupSort() {
        List<Record> records = asList(
                new Record("a", 3),
                new Record("a", 9),
                new Record("b", 7),
                new Record("b", 10),
                new Record("c", 8),
                new Record("c", 3));

        List<SortedMap<Integer, Record>> recordsGroupedByName = groupRecordsByNameAndSortedByScoreDescending(records);
        Collections.sort(recordsGroupedByName, byHighestScoreInGroupDescending());
        List<Record> result = flattenGroups(recordsGroupedByName);

        List<Record> expected = asList(
                new Record("b", 10),
                new Record("b", 7),
                new Record("a", 9),
                new Record("a", 3),
                new Record("c", 8),
                new Record("c", 3));

        assertEquals(expected, result);
    }

    private List<Record> flattenGroups(List<SortedMap<Integer, Record>> recordGroups) {
        List<Record> result = new ArrayList<Record>();
        for (SortedMap<Integer, Record> group : recordGroups) {
            result.addAll(group.values());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private List<SortedMap<Integer, Record>> groupRecordsByNameAndSortedByScoreDescending(List<Record> records) {
        Map<String, SortedMap<Integer, Record>> groupsByName = new HashMap<String, SortedMap<Integer, Record>>();
        for (Record record : records) {
            SortedMap<Integer, Record> group = groupsByName.get(record.getName());
            if (null == group) {
                group = new TreeMap<Integer, Record>(descending());
                groupsByName.put(record.getName(), group);
            }
            group.put(record.getScore(), record);
        }
        return new ArrayList<SortedMap<Integer, Record>>(groupsByName.values());
    }

    private DescendingSortComparator descending() {
        return new DescendingSortComparator();
    }

    private ByFirstKeyDescending byHighestScoreInGroupDescending() {
        return new ByFirstKeyDescending();
    }

    private static class ByFirstKeyDescending implements Comparator<SortedMap<Integer, Record>> {
        public int compare(SortedMap<Integer, Record> o1, SortedMap<Integer, Record> o2) {
            return o2.firstKey().compareTo(o1.firstKey());
        }
    }

    private static class DescendingSortComparator implements Comparator<Comparable> {
        public int compare(Comparable o1, Comparable o2) {
            return o2.compareTo(o1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Amir: Except that none of the other answers actually read the question which asked about sorting names by the highest score for each name. The other answers only tell you how to sort individual records by score and name without grouping by name, which is not the same thing.

Comment: What are you talking about? It sorts by name first then by score. This works. I have tried it myself.

Comment: @Amir: Which is not what the question was about. The question wants all the b:s sorted first because one of the b:s has the highest score overall, and then all the a:s after that because one of the a:s has the second score overall, and so on. If you know SQL, he wants `GROUP BY name ORDER BY MAX(score), score DESC`, not `ORDER BY name, score` (sort of).

Comment: @pmeidl: I'd appreciate it if you'd accept my answer.

Comment: Not found symbol `comparingInt`. For methods `groupingBy()` and `toList()` the class Collectors has to be specified.

Comment: @Alex78191: Thanks, and also you need to `import java.util.*`. I added the imports.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström I think the answer has not changed.

Comment: @Alex78191: Haha, thanks again, i actually hadn't pressed Save. :)

Answer (score 2):

Foreach over the collection, and put the objects into a `Map<String, SortedSet<YourObject>>`, keyed by name, where the SortedSet is a TreeSet with a custom comparator that compares by score.

Then foreach over the map's values() collection, and put the groups into a `SortedSet<SortedSet<YourObject>>`, with a second custom comparator that compares SortedSets according to their largest element. Actually, instead of foreaching, you can simply use addAll().

Here's the code:

```
public class SortThings {

    static class Thing {
        public final String name;
        public final int score;
        public Thing(String name, int score) {
            this.name = name;
            this.score = score;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "(" + name + ", " + score + ")";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Collection<Thing> things = Arrays.asList(
            new Thing("a", 3),
            new Thing("a", 9),
            new Thing("b", 7),
            new Thing("b", 10),
            new Thing("c", 8),
            new Thing("c", 3)
        );

        SortedSet<SortedSet<Thing>> sortedGroups = sortThings(things);

        System.out.println(sortedGroups);
    }

    private static SortedSet<SortedSet<Thing>> sortThings(Collection<Thing> things) {
        final Comparator<Thing> compareThings = new Comparator<Thing>() {
            public int compare(Thing a, Thing b) {
                Integer aScore = a.score;
                Integer bScore = b.score;
                return aScore.compareTo(bScore);
            }
        };

        // first pass
        Map<String, SortedSet<Thing>> groups = new HashMap<String, SortedSet<Thing>>();
        for (Thing obj: things) {
            SortedSet<Thing> group = groups.get(obj.name);
            if (group == null) {
                group = new TreeSet<Thing>(compareThings);
                groups.put(obj.name, group);
            }
            group.add(obj);
        }

        // second pass
        SortedSet<SortedSet<Thing>> sortedGroups = new TreeSet<SortedSet<Thing>>(new Comparator<SortedSet<Thing>>() {
            public int compare(SortedSet<Thing> a, SortedSet<Thing> b) {
                return compareThings.compare(a.last(), b.last());
            }
        });
        sortedGroups.addAll(groups.values());
        return sortedGroups;
    }

}
```

Note that the output is in smallest-to-largest order. That's the natural order with Java's collections; it would be trivial to modify this to sort the other way if that's what you need.

Comment: Either use `SortedMap` or you have to sort each set by both score and identity to handle duplicates.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström: as far as i can tell, my code handles duplicate Things (by deduplicating them). Could you expand on what you meant?

Comment: Deduplicating them isn't really handling them though. If i put in two equal but not identical Thing, i want two equal but not identical Thing in the result.You just made me realize that i have the same bug myself though! D'oh! :)

Comment: @Christoffer: We don't know for sure what the right thing to do with duplicates is. If the OP's goal is just to get the groups in order, deduplicating is fine. If not, then yes, this code is incorrect; the fix would be to change compareThings to break ties somehow (i think it would have to be arbitrary, eg by hashcode). And i still don't see how a SortedMap would help.

Comment: You're right on both accounts, a `SortedMap` does not help. That was just a misthought on my part. Also, you're right that we don't know that the OP cares about duplicates. I just think it's usually more likely that you'd want a non-destructive algorithm, and since it's a slightly harder problem to solve, the solution would be more complete if it preserved duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class ScoreComparator implements Comparator<Item>
{

  public int compare(Item a, Item b){

    if (a.name.equals(b.name){
      return a.score.compareTo(b.score);
    }

    return a.name.compareTo(b.Name);    

  }

}
```

Comment: I downvoted, because this sorts by name and then score, which is not the same as grouping by name and sorting them by highest score within the group.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Go for [`Comparator`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

Give first preference to `name` in comparison and then to score. it will be grouped up with sorted score also

```
    List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();
    scores.add(new Score("a", 58));
    scores.add(new Score("a", 10));
    scores.add(new Score("b", 165));
    scores.add(new Score("a", 1));
    scores.add(new Score("b", 1658));
    scores.add(new Score("c", 1));
    scores.add(new Score("c", 10));
    scores.add(new Score("c", 0));

    Collections.sort(scores, new Comparator<Score>() {

        public int compare(Score o1, Score o2) {
            if (o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()) == 0) {
                return o2.getScore() - o1.getScore();
            } else {
                return o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName());
            }
        }
    });
    System.out.println(scores);
```

### Update

As Chris pointed out.

```
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Jigar
 */
class Score {

    private String name;
    private List<Integer> scores;

    public Score() {
    }

    public Score(String name, List<Integer> scores) {
        this.name = name;
        this.scores = scores;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<Integer> getScores() {
        return scores;
    }

    public void setScores(List<Integer> scores) {
        this.scores = scores;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + " , " + scores + "\n";
    }
}

public class ScoreDemo { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Score> scores = new ArrayList<Score>();


        List<Integer> lstA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lstA.add(3);
        lstA.add(9);
        lstA.add(7);
        Collections.sort(lstA);
        Collections.reverse(lstA);

        List<Integer> lstB = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lstB.add(10);
        lstB.add(8);
        lstB.add(3);
        Collections.sort(lstB);
        Collections.reverse(lstB);

        List<Integer> lstC = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        lstC.add(8);
        lstC.add(3);
        Collections.sort(lstC);
        Collections.reverse(lstC);


        scores.add(new Score("a", lstA));
        scores.add(new Score("b", lstB));
        scores.add(new Score("c", lstC));





        Collections.sort(scores, new Comparator<Score>() {

            public int compare(Score o1, Score o2) {
                return o2.getScores().get(0).compareTo(o1.getScores().get(0));
            }
        });
        System.out.println(scores);

    }
}
```

- [Here is **working** ideone demo](http://ideone.com/wFGZE)
- [**UPDATE**: Here is **working** ideone demo](http://ideone.com/kvmDk)

Comment: Someone is just going around and downvoting. It happened to my other post also. It is annoying. +1 for good answer though. I would have instead use the eqauls() function.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: why, and why didn't you also downvote Adam Batkin's answer, which is substantially the same?

Comment: @Tom don't worry, they got mine too

Comment: I downvoted, because this sorts by name and then score, which is not the same as grouping by name and sorting them by highest score within the group.

Comment: @Adam, point isn't that, This activity is performed very often now a days. and it is completely illogical.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström  doesn't matter, final result matters. and I request you to put comment from now if you downvote.

Comment: @Jigar: Try your code with the example input and expected result from the question and you'll see that your final result is wrong. Note that b sorts before a because the highest score in group b is higher than the highest score in group a.

Comment: @Christoffer Hammarström Thanks I got your point, But I don't think OP is asking for that

Comment: @Jigar: The OP gives example input and expected output in his question. Just put it in a unit test and do `assertEquals(expected, result)`, you can copy it from my answer.

Comment: @Chris Thanks updated the post. This isn't the most optimized way but this will work for sure. and you can always optimize it. like you can use own Comparator instead using natural and then reversing.. and other things, I have just kept the concept ahead.

Comment: @Jigar: It would behoove you to start with a list and end with a list so you can do the aforementioned `assertEquals(expected, result)`, right now you don't even start with a list of Objects as in the question.

Comment: @Chris yes it will met the OP's requirement now.

Comment: @Jigar: I don't see how? The OPs requirement was to sort a flat list of objects into another flat list of objects, while in your answer you have three lists and 8 integers, and end up with a list containing three lists? It's not at all the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this. First check to see if the group is equal. If it is then compare on score. Otherwise return which group you want to be more on top. Let me code it up.

```
    class Item{
      String name;
      int score;
    }

   new Comparator<Item>(){

       @Override
       public int compare(Item o1, Item o2) {
            if (o1.name.equals(o2.name)) {
                return o1.score > o2.score ? 1 : -1; // might have to flip this. I didn't test
            }else {
                return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
            }
       }
    };
```

Comment: I downvoted, because this sorts by name and then score, which is not the same as grouping by name and sorting them by highest score within the group.

Comment: I must agree with you. I was unclear at first. But if he want the highest group score to be on top then indeed this is not possible. Sorry for the confusion.